# show tables result into a temp table mysql

Tags: mysql

`Show Tables` command shows all the tables presented in current database.

We can also use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` for table information.

But i'm not in the position to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

Can any one tell me

How can we insert result of 'Show Tables' command into a table.

Comment: "Each MySQL user has the right to access these tables, but can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user has the proper access privileges." I hope you can get the informations from Information_schema table itself.

Comment: Plz read question ones again.I clearly mention there that i am not in the position to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.That is the only region behind posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do the same thing. Here are several examples.
I also needed to create tables containing stored procedures and functions,
so at the end of the examples I show how to create tables containing procedures and functions.

```
/*______________________________________
    Quick Version only showing tables.
    No where clause, No table_schema
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   tmp_tables;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tables
SELECT
    *
FROM
    information_schema.tables;

SELECT * FROM tmp_tables;


/*____________________________________________________
    Quick Version with a table name filter
    '%' is a wild card so in this example the results
    may look somthing like:

    TABLE_NAME
    ---------------------
    tbl_employee
    tbl_albumns
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   tmp_tables;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tables
SELECT
    *
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_name like 'tbl_%';

SELECT * FROM tmp_tables;


/*______________________________________
    This version shows all the column names
    in the select seciton.
    Use with or without the where clause
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   tmp_tables;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tables
SELECT
    TABLE_CATALOG,
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME,
    TABLE_TYPE,
    ENGINE,
    VERSION,
    ROW_FORMAT,
    TABLE_ROWS,
    AVG_ROW_LENGTH,
    DATA_LENGTH,
    MAX_DATA_LENGTH,
    INDEX_LENGTH,
    DATA_FREE,
    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CREATE_TIME,
    UPDATE_TIME,
    CHECK_TIME,
    TABLE_COLLATION,
    CHECKSUM,
    CREATE_OPTIONS,
    TABLE_COMMENT
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_schema = DATABASE() # This looks in the current database (schema)
    AND
    table_name like 'tbl_%';

SELECT * FROM tmp_tables;


/*______________________________________
    Quick Version only showing tables.
    Use with or without the where clause
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   tmp_tables;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tables
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_schema = 'database_name_quoted' #This looks in a specfic database (schema)
    AND
    table_name like '%_tbl_%';

SELECT * FROM tmp_tables;


#==================================
#SOME EXTRA STUFF...
#----------------------------------
# Again these can be used with out
# the WHERE clause or specfic
# elements in the WHERE clause...

# CREATE A TABLE OF PROCEDURES...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   tmp_tables;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tables
SELECT
    *
FROM
    information_schema.routines
WHERE
    ROUTINE_SCHEMA = database()
    and
    ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
    AND
    ROUTINE_NAME like 'proc_%';

SELECT * FROM tmp_tables;

# CREATE A TABLE OF FUNCTIONS...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   tmp_tables;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tables
SELECT
    *
FROM
    information_schema.routines
WHERE
    ROUTINE_SCHEMA = database()
    and
    ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
    AND
    ROUTINE_NAME like 'func_%';

SELECT * FROM tmp_tables;
```

OOPS. I didn't read you question very thoroughly, I found a way to create a comma delimited list of database names, I modified the method to return a comma delimited list of tables.

**The following code creates a temporary table that holds all the table names in a database, it *does not* use information_schema.**
I was able to get a comma delimited list of table names using information from: [Shlomi Noach](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reading-results-of-show-statements-on-server-side)

```
/*
    This comes from: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reading-results-of-show-statements-on-server-side

    This produces a comma delimited string of tables
    in 'databasename'

    So if your database name is: my_database
    the column name will be: `Tables_in_my_database`

SET @tablename := '';
SHOW TABLES WHERE (@tablename := concat(@tablename, `Tables_in_databasename`, ',')) IS NULL;
SELECT @tablename;

*/


DELIMITER ;;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TableList; ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE TableList(IN DatabaseName TEXT, OUT TableList TEXT)
begin
    DEclare ColumnName text;

    SET ColumnName = CONCAT('`Tables_in_', DatabaseName, '`');
    SET @holder = '';

    SET @statement =
    CONCAT
    (
        'SHOW TABLES WHERE (@holder := CONCAT(@holder, ',
        columnname,
        ', ', '\'', ',', '\'', '));'  
    );

    PREPARE statement FROM @statement;
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;

    SET TableList = @holder;

    #Create the temporary table that will hold the table names...
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   tmp_table_list;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table_list (TableName text);

    #Loop through our table list...
    ListLoop: LOOP
        #Check if we are done with the list...
        IF LOCATE(',', @Holder) = 0 THEN
            LEAVE ListLoop;
        END IF;

        #Get the first table name from the list...
        SET @TableName = LEFT(@Holder, (LOCATE(',', @Holder) - 1));

        #Insert our table name into our temporary table...
        INSERT INTO tmp_table_list (TableName) VALUES (@TableName);

        #Remove our table name and the first comma from the table name list...
        SET @Holder = RIGHT(@Holder, LENGTH(@Holder) - (LENGTH(@TableName) + 1));
    END LOOP;

    #We don't have to select and drop our table here
    #But we will for this example...
    SELECT * FROM tmp_table_list;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_table_list;
end;
;;

DELIMITER ;

#SET YOUR DATABASENAME HERE
#                       |
#                       V
CALL TableList('databasename', @TableList);

#SELECT * FROM tmp_table_list;

#SELECT @TableList;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please select data from table and create temp table like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table1)
```

Comment: Yes you are right we can fill data into temp table using this query.
But my question is to fill the result of `Show Tables` into a temp table.And this is not working with `Show Tables`.